# Scala type class to extend generic type: No implicits found for parameter

Tags: scala, generics, typeclass

I want to write a type class, to add some behavior to a generic type. However, I cannot figure out how to do it; I keep running into the error below.

Imagine you have a generic type `MyList[A]`:

```scala
trait MyList[A]

object MyList {
  case class Empty[A]() extends MyList[A]
  case class Node[A](value: A, next: MyList[A]) extends MyList[A]
}
```

Now you want to add some behavior to this class, e.g. to convert it into a `Stream[A]`. A type class based extension would seem appropriate:

```scala
// inspired by https://scalac.io/typeclasses-in-scala

trait MyListExt[T, A <: MyList[T]] {
  def stream(a: A): Stream[T]
}

object MyListExt {
  def apply[T, A <: MyList[T]](implicit a: MyListExt[T, A]): MyListExt[T, A] = a

  object ops {
    implicit class MyListExtOps[T, A <: MyList[T]](val a: A) extends AnyVal {
      def stream(implicit ext: MyListExt[T, A]): Stream[T] = ext.stream(a)
    }
  }

  private type T0

  implicit val myListToStreamImpl: MyListExt[T0, MyList[T0]] = new MyListExt[T0, MyList[T0]] {
    override def stream(a: MyList[T0]): Stream[T0] = {
      def fold[T1](l: MyList[T1], acc: Stream[T1]): Stream[T1] = l match {
        case MyList.Empty() => acc
        case MyList.Node(value, next) => fold(next, acc :+ value)
      }
      fold(a, Stream.empty)
    }
  }
}
```

When I now try to use this type class in my code, I get the following error at `l.stream`:

> ```
> No implicits found for parameter ext: MyListExt[T_, MyList[Int]]
> ```

```scala
object MyListTest {
  def main(args: Array[String]): Unit = {
    import MyListExt.ops._
    val l: MyList[Int] = MyList.Node(1, MyList.Node(2, MyList.Node(3, MyList.Empty())))
    l.stream.foreach(println)
  }
}
```

What am I doing wrong, or how can I get my `l.stream` to work?
I have seen many examples involving type classes and implicit conversion, but none so far operating on generic types.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
  implicit def myListToStreamImpl[T]: MyListExt[T, MyList[T]] = new MyListExt[T, MyList[T]] {
    override def stream(a: MyList[T]): Stream[T] = {
      def fold(l: MyList[T1], acc: Stream[T1]): Stream[T1] = l match {
        case MyList.Empty() => acc
        case MyList.Node(value, next) => fold(next, acc :+ value)
      }
      fold(a, Stream.empty[T1])
    }
  }
```

Your types don't align because you've used that `private type` for whatever bizarre reason. Types nested inside objects have a completely different application, and they don't relate to your current use case.

Comment: Please provide a full example of your proposed solution, as the proposed `implicit val myListToStreamImpl[T]: ...` ends with a `Cannot resolve Symbol T` compiler error. Edit: I see you exchanged `val` for `def`. this works

Answer (score 1):

The trouble is that in `l.stream.foreach(println)` the `l` is implicitly transformed to `new MyListExt.ops.MyListExtOps[.., ..](l)` and generics  are inferred to be `[Nothing, MyList[Int]]`, which doesn't satisfy `[T, A <: MyList[T]]`.

I can't see reason to parametrize `MyListExt` with both `T` and `A <: MyList[T]`. I guess `T` is enough, use `MyList[T]` instead of `A`.

Don't use `private type T0`, just parametrize `myListToStreamImpl` (make it `def`) with `T0` aka `T`.

Try

```
  trait MyList[A]

  object MyList {
    case class Empty[A]() extends MyList[A]
    case class Node[A](value: A, next: MyList[A]) extends MyList[A]
  }

  trait MyListExt[T] {
    def stream(a: MyList[T]): Stream[T]
  }

  object MyListExt {
    def apply[T](implicit a: MyListExt[T]): MyListExt[T] = a

    object ops {
      implicit class MyListExtOps[T](val a: MyList[T]) extends AnyVal {
        def stream(implicit ext: MyListExt[T]): Stream[T] = ext.stream(a)
      }
    }

    implicit def myListToStreamImpl[T]: MyListExt[T] = new MyListExt[T] {
      override def stream(a: MyList[T]): Stream[T] = {
        def fold[T1](l: MyList[T1], acc: Stream[T1]): Stream[T1] = l match {
          case MyList.Empty() => acc
          case MyList.Node(value, next) => fold(next, acc :+ value)
        }
        fold(a, Stream.empty)
      }
    }
  }

  object MyListTest {
    def main(args: Array[String]): Unit = {
      import MyListExt.ops._
      val l: MyList[Int] = MyList.Node(1, MyList.Node(2, MyList.Node(3, MyList.Empty())))
      l.stream.foreach(println)
    }
  }
```

Comment: Thanks for the explanation. Regarding the use of the 2nd generic parameter `A` on my trait `MyListExt`, in the _real_ problem I am trying to solve, I need to have access to a member of my `A`, so I am limiting the whole thing a little bit